# path to downloaded Bing Wallpapers

Tags: windows, bing

I have just read [this](http://archive.feedblitz.com/118118/~4142301) article which provides the generic theme template and some changes to be made to it so that when applied that theme downloads the bing wallpapers from the wallpaper server feed and applies to the desktop background.

It seems that my PC have downloaded most of them but I want to know where they are actually stored on my harddrive so that I can access them.

I am running Windows 8 RP.

Answer (score 0):

By default, it saves the downloaded image (only one) and keeps replacing it everytime it downloads a new one. (I've tested it!)

The Path is: (Replace "YourUsername" by whatever is your username is when u login into Windows)

```
C:\Users\YourUsername\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Themes
```

Comment: nope its not there :(  Themes directory have one file TranscodedWallpaper and a folder CachedFiles which contains a single wallpapers and that wallpaperd is not from Bing feed.

Any other guess?

Comment: that TranscodedWallpaper keeps changing if u have selected Change Wallpapers from RSS Feed. I just tried it again ..

Comment: That file doesn't have file type. So I just copy pasted it to desktop and then changed its extension to .jpg, now it is my current desktop background. Actually the CachedFiles folder also contains the same wallpaper. 
I think applying that theme downloads all the wallpapers from the feed as said in that post. When I applied the theme first time, it showed dialog on which I clicked Download Attachments. Then my bandwidth was used for long time by Theme process as I saw in TaskManager. Also when I went to the feed link it showed the list of all wallpapers downloaded and pending. (cntd...)

Comment: http://s15.postimage.org/hffz6q7q3/Untitled.png
I thought it must have downloaded all the wallapapers. Where can I grab them all?

Comment: for me its `TranscodedWallpaper.jpg` only. It downloads all the wallpapers, but replaces the same one. Open that generic.theme in notepad, change the time interval to 1800, and ull know it keeps refreshing..

Comment: you can grab them all here : http://themeserver.microsoft.com/default.aspx?p=Bing&c=Desktop&m=en-US

Comment: It replaces that file by downloading the new wallpaper from the web when changed the wallpaper? I think it must be having them all downloaded on the harddrive to change the wallpapers when offline. So do you know the directory path? Or may be Microsoft not willing to share the path for copyrights?!?!?

Comment: arey you mean downloading them by individually clicking download link?

Comment: yes, it replaces it while changing the wallpaper. It needs the internet to change background. It wont work otherwise coz its coming from an RSS Feed. You can read all the details here : http://www.sheldonsingh.com/free/animated-desktop-background-with-bing-wallpapers/

Comment: You can do it manually / individually, or you can automate it using a web grabber / website downloader..

Comment: U know any such downloader that can grab all such links?

Comment: search HTTrack by Xavier Roche, it's a freeware, you will find how to use it over google search..

Comment: hey thanks I am done. Though not able to find the path, I downloaded then from feed link using DownThemAll! firefox extension

Answer (score 0):

All the downloaded photos for a theme can be found at the following folder on Win 8 RP:
C:\Users\<*UserName*>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Enclosure\{99ADCA45-0F02-4A67-80E7-6FFA68493920}

Or just go to the Enclosure folder and see if there is any folder with name following similar above number pattern. For example on Win 7 it may be {AA03285A-3998-464A-832C-ACF130FCC85A}

Answer (score -1):

I found the images here
C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\BingDesktop\en-US\Apps\Wallpaper_5386c77076d04cf9a8b5d619b4cba48e\VersionIndependent\images